# How to change size of the LinearLayout when it is runtime?

Tags: android

How to change the size of LinearLayout when it is runtime ?

I've set the size dynamically when it is runtime. But no luck. Didn't change the size of LinearLayout.

How to code it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size is determined by the `LayoutParams` connecting the `LinearLayout` with its parent.

Comment: I am using following code to set the size of LinearLayout when call public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);
layout.height = h;
layout.width = w;
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layout);
linearLayout.setYardageActivity(this);

Above code worked fine at first time. Then when it is runtime, called above code again. No luck. It were same size like its old.

Can you suggest any coding to correct the above code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do that:

```
// get element I want to resize
LinearLayout myBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.infopanel_graph); 

// get layout parameters for that element
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myBar.getLayoutParams();

// change width of the params e.g. 50dp
params.width = 50;

// initialize new parameters for my element
myBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(params));
```

Comment: When I ran above code. It crashed at the last line. We do not need to call setLayoutParams. When you say params.width =50, that much width gets assigned to the LinearLayout.